# Unable to submit laravel 5.6 form

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I am displaying a list of items and each has an edit button that pops up a modal when clicked which works well like this

```
@foreach ($testimonials as $item)
<tr class="text-muted">
    <td class="text-capitalize">{{ $item->firstname }}</td>
    <td class="text-capitalize">{{ $item->lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->comment }}</td>
    <td class="text-capitalize">@if ($item->status === 0) hidden @else showing @endif</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn-custom-one" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editTestimonial{{$item->id}}">Edit</button> 
    </td>
</tr>

{{-- Edit Modal --}}
<div class="modal fade" id="editTestimonial{{$item->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="/home/testimonials/{{$item->id}}/update" method="POST">
                    @method('PUT')
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{$item->firstname}}" class="form-control" aria-describedby="firstname">
                            <small id="firstname" class="text-muted">Firstname</small>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="{{$item->lastname}}" class="form-control" aria-describedby="lastname">
                            <small id="lastname" class="text-muted">Lastname</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
                        <textarea name="comment" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" aria-describedby="comment">{{$item->comment}}</textarea>
                        <small id="comment" class="text-muted">Client's comment</small>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-two">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

The update route is `Route::put('/home/testimonials/{testimonial}/update', 'TestimonialController@update');`

TestimonialController update function is like this right now

```
public function update(Request $request, Testimonial $testimonial)
{
dd($request)
}
```

The problem now is that when the save button is clicked to submit the form, nothing happens. But if I move the modal outside the foreach statement, the form works well but only the last item's edit button pops up a modal. The others don't. How can I fix my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Is there any JS handler preventing the submission?

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean the form is not submitted and I remain on the same page with the modal and nothing is dumped by the update function. Note if I remove the modal from inside the foreach statement, the form submits successfully.

Comment: So, is the form submitted (which means: your browser triggers something, sends the data to the backend) or not?

Comment: @NicoHaase the form is not submitted, no data is sent to the backend.

Comment: So, how do you check for a dump by any backend function then? And what blocks that request? JS code?

Comment: @Mena Problem seems with generated HTML, you are putting `tr` followed by `div`. just try to move modal `div` inside the `td` and see.

Comment: @jagad89 I just tried that and that didn't fix it for me.

Comment: @NicoHaase There is no error in the console so I cannot say a JS code is blocking the form submission. I can check if form request was sent to the back end using `dd`

Comment: But if no submission takes place, the backend code is never triggered. So you should check using the developer tools whether there are any JS event handlers that block the submission

Comment: Not necessarily the issue, but you have conflicting methods: `<form ... method="POST"> ... @method('PUT')` Your route is setup to use `Route::put()`, so configure your form to match.

Comment: @TimLewis from 5.6 documentation on [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing) the form hidden method field can be used to specify that the method is PUT and not POST since HTML does not support PUT. The form however works well when it is moved outside the foreach statement so the methods are not conflicting.

Comment: Ah, nice catch! Didn't know that (but it's been a while since I've had to use anything but `GET` or `POST`).